# Plot a toroid with rectangular cross-section in 3D

Tags: gnuplot, 3d-graphics

Does anybody know how to plot with gnuplot in 3D the surface of a disk on the `XY`-plane with a certain thickness, and having a circular hole in the center and flat upper and lower surfaces at fixed `z` (a torus flattened on the upper and lower surfaces).

Answer (score 0):

Because your shape has vertical tangents, it cannot be written as `z=f(x,y)`, so `splot <function>` cannot be used. However, you can plot data from a file, see e.g. a solution to plot cubes: http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-cubes/

In order to use gnuplot to generate the data itself, you can use the pseudo-file "++" and modifiers, here's how to plot a cylinder:

```
splot [-1:1][-1:1][0:1] '++' u (cos(pi*$1)):(sin(pi*$1)):($2) w lines
```

For plotting the top surface, you can use the same trick:

```
replot '++' u ($2*cos(pi*$1)):($2*sin(pi*$1)):1 w lines
```

For your precise shape, minor changes of these are needed. I advise that you define functions for the x and y coordinate calculations, they can use `GPVAL_X_MIN` and co. in order to normalise the variables `$1` and `$2` in the relevant range independently of the plotting ranges.